# Not able to SSH into Raspberry Pi3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I am not able to SSH to Raspberry Pi 3 from Putty. I can ping the 192.168.137.1 IP address assigned by sharing Internet connection. Note: I do not have HDMI monitor so need to access remotely only. 
The problem I realized that SSH is not enabled by default in Pi3 and saw the posts which suggest to enable SSH by creating 'ssh' file inside /boot folder. I got the SD card which has pre-installed Noobs so when I open SD card it shows only /recovery folder. How to enable SSH in this case ? Please help to resolve it .

Even if i get monitor which supports HDMI, it seems i need to edit the display settings to adjust the screen resoltuion to 1920 *1080 by changing /boot/config.txt file. But i can not see boot folder in SD card. Please help to resolve this.

Comment: It is **extremely** unlikely that `192.168.137.1` is the IP address of the Pi! Your question is lacking detail (of config), but it appears you are using ICS. If this is so you cannot also `ssh` over the link. You can have **either** ICS or local access (without complex bridging). Connect the Pi to your router.

Answer (score 2):

If you can somehow get the display up and running, you can enable SSH from raspi-config. For me the 'ssh' file in /boot partition didn't work. But I'll give you a walkthrough anyway, since I saw some false info in your post.

## NOTE

Try using Raspbian instead of NOOBS, since it's a bit less complicated (yes, believe me).

## Enable SSH from raspi-config

These instructions assume you have working internet connection.

1. Run `sudo raspi-config`
2. Select Interfacing options
3. Select SSH
4. Select Enable
5. Reboot
6. SSH into it.

## Enable SSH from /boot

These instructions assume you have working internet connection.

1. Plug in your sd card to any computer that supports it.
2. Find partition called boot, it's FAT32. It's not a folder, but a partition.
3. Create an empty file called `ssh`, without any extensions.
4. Insert your sd card into the RPi and wait for it to boot.
5. SSH into it.

Link to official [guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/)

Comment: Did you, by accident, try to create `/boot/ssh` on the *root* partition, instead of creating`ssh` on the *boot* position?

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest to use noobs which makes a lot of thinks much more complicated.

Install Raspbian on a SD card instead. Next create a file called 'ssh' on the boot partition.

If you have a Linux box handy mount the SD card and partition mmcblk0p1. Then just execute

`touch ssh`

If you use Windows the boot partition will be mounted as soon as you plug in the SD card. Open any editor you are familiar with on Windows and create a file called 'ssh' and save it.

That way your Raspi will enable the ssh port when booting :-)